# fontconfig wont' install because it's missing freetype

Tags: debian, freetype, fontconfig

I have installed freetype2.5.5, but fontconfig's latest git repository will not find it.  I get the following error:

```
./configure: line 14023: syntax error near unexpected toke 'FREETYPE,'
./configure: line 14023: 'PKG_CHECK_MODULES (FREETYPE, freetype2)'
```

Could you advise me in what to do?  I could change its configure file to point to freetype, but I don't know which configure file to edit.  Thanks.

Comment: freetype's cmake is not making freetype.pc; I am not sure how to get it

Comment: apparently you can go into freetype-2.5.5/docs/ and find your install readme

Comment: talking to myself; even if it's on a stackexchange forum, does help jog my mind into thinking of solutions; that and lots of prayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently freetype's cmake does not create all of the files you need; go into the docs folder and read the install instructions for your OS; it still did not create "freetype.pc" but fontconfig's configure script created the makefile for me.  Thank God.